# minitest testing and code coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, minitest

I use `mini-test` for testing framework. I use `omniauth` gem for authentication. I use `simplecov` for code coverage. I run my tests using `"bundle exec rake"` or `"rake minitest:controllers"`. I give an example for controllers. When I run `rake minitest:controllers`, controllers code coverage becomes 100%. But, when I run `bundle exec rake`, controllers code coverage become 60%.

SessionsController.rb code:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     person=Person.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth.provider,auth.uid) || Person.create_with_omniauth(auth)
     redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

SessionsController_test.rb

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe SessionsController do
  before do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:identity] 
    @person = Fabricate.build(:person)
  end

  it "should create authentication" do
    assert_difference('Person.count') do
      post :create, :provider => "identity"
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_path @person
  end
end
```

I wonder that if I miss one point on writing test. I wait your ideas. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

minitest_helper.rb

```
require 'simplecov'
Simplecov.start

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/pride"
require 'database_cleaner'
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

require "minitest-mongoid"

DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
#OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:identity, {
    :uid => '12345'

})


class MiniTest::Spec
 before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: For your differences in code coverage, this is normal.  The coverage is measured on the tests ran.  So for the overall, you would run all tests, and the coverage would be recorded for that.

Comment: Sorry. But, I'm a bit confused when I read your answer. Are my coverage results normal? In our project, we accept 100% coverage. My leader wants this. Is there anyway to ensure 100% coverage? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Can you post the coverage summary that's generated for each run? Perhaps in a gist? I think that would help us get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: If it is reporting coverage that is less than what you expect, then there may be a problem, other than complying with 100% coverage.  The point is, that when using rcov, it will show the coverage for the area under test at that moment.  To ensure that the full coverage report (whether or not the actuality is 100%) run the full suite to record it at that moment in time.

Comment: Can you post your minitest_helper? I suspect you're loading simplecov too late, it has to be required at the very first line of the spec helper. Also, which exact ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Simplecov's documentation](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#getting-started), you just have to add theses lines in top of your `test/test_helper.rb`:

```rb
# test/test_helper.rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
# ...
```

Also do not forget to install simplecov gem in test group:

```rb
# Gemfile
# ...
group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
end
```

And that's it.

**Rails 6**: I encountered some issues with Rails 6 and tests paralelization so you may deactivate it in `test/test_helper.rb`:

```rb
# test/test_helper.rb
# ...
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # ...
  # parallelize(workers: 2)
end
```

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. Disabling parallelization fixed it. Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell with no more information.

First of all try `rake minitest:all` and update your question with the result.

Please try following in case the former test did not conclude positively:

```
namespace :test do
  task :coverage do
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails' # feel free to pass block
    Rake::Task["test"].execute
  end
end
```

Let us know and we can edit or update the answer.

Minitest is known to have had some issues with it. I believe it was still work in progress, not sure where they stand now. It is not you, it's minitest. That workaround helped in some cases, maybe it helps you too.

Comment: The answer is from 2015. Rails 6 did not exist back then. Please feel free to add suggestions if you can help.

Comment: Yes I understand that but the question is not flagged as Rails 5. I simply warn that if someone try this with Rails 6 this may not work.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I saw you contributed with an answer complementing the solutions. Good move, upvoted.